# how to deploy django/react app to heroku with different directory structure

Tags: django, reactjs, heroku, deployment

I have a django/react app I created using this tutorial [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-to-do-application-using-django-and-react)

Although slightly different, I then tried to deploy my app to heroku using this tutorial [here](https://librenepal.com/article/django-and-create-react-app-together-on-heroku/)

The directory structure following the tutorials are different though. My directory structure is as follows...

```
django-todo-react/
  backend/
    backend/
    todo/
    manage.py
    ...
  frontend/
    all my react stuff...
```

in my django-todo-react folder (the project root directory) I have `requirements.txt`, `Procfile`, `package.json`, and '.gitignore` file.

To my understanding the `Procfile` should contain something like `web: gunicorn backend.wsgi` but because my `Procfile` is in the root directory I do instead the following `web: gunicorn backend/backend.wsgi` that looks very weird but basically I go into my backend folder where I have my actual backend project I started with `django-admin startproject backend` and get `wsgi`.

I added all the other stuff from the second tutorial I mentioned [this one](https://librenepal.com/article/django-and-create-react-app-together-on-heroku/) but still no such luck. I get a `COLLECT_STATIC` error and if I silence the error everything passes but I then get a `application error` when opening my heroku app.

I have already tried deploying an app just using the 2nd tutorial and all worked fine but that had the directory structure of the second tutorial. I thought that changing my `Procfile` to have `web: gunicorn backend/backend.wsgi` would point to the right thing.

So I basically just want to have a server folder which in my case is my backend folder and a client folder which for me it's frontend. This is not working for me though.

Answer (score 0):

Gunicorn expects Python-like paths, so in your case using `web: gunicorn django-todo-react.backend.backend.wsgi` in `Procfile` should work.

Comment: I see, thanks. I changed that being of course that it would be a problem in my application but still have this error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/build_5654aafc/backend/frontend/build/static'` which is the same `Error while running '$ python backend/manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.` error I keep seeing

Answer (score 0):

So I've been trying to figure out the solution to my problem and see that after carefully reading the console for any errors that `collectstatic` is not finding my `static` folder. It looks for my static folder from within the Django project then a frontend folder, a build folder, and lastly a static.

My Django project does not have a frontend folder so instead of creating my react app in the root of my directory I create it in my Django project and make sure to run yarn build so that my frontend folder contains the build/static

This works fine so if anyone is having an issue with a similar thing I hope this helps. Also, my question still stands on how to get it working with having two separate directories one for my backend and one for my frontend. I am pretty sure it has to do with the `STATIC_DIRS` but that is just a guess